# Xoring strings and getting only hex back

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take a path

```
C:\windows\programs\test
```

And then xor it against a random key the same length of the path

```
4deebb6172406e69316df004e38334a5f6c1a80c8b865800
```

I generate a key using

```
binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(24))
```

When they are XOR'd against each other, I am given a string that looks like:

```
b'\x02\x0cj@Y[\x05\x0cN@>GAYRBV\x0fD=GP\x16@'
```

My question is, is it possible to get an output that is only hex? Instead of generating all the characters, keep it (a-f, A-F, 0-9)?

Comment: You have confused data and its representation. You work and calculate with binary data and you display it to a human as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

The byte string is actually just a series of numbers from 0 to 255.  You can see this via:

```
list(b'\x02\x0cj@Y[\x05\x0cN@>GAYRBV\x0fD=GP\x16@')
# returns:
[2,
 12,
 106,
 64,
 89,
 91,
 5,
 12,
 78,
 64,
 62,
 71,
 65,
 89,
 82,
 66,
 86,
 15,
 68,
 61,
 71,
 80,
 22,
 64]
```

You can convert the byte string to a sequence of hex digits of length 2 via:

```
''.join(f'{b:0>2x}' for b in b'\x02\x0cj@Y[\x05\x0cN@>GAYRBV\x0fD=GP\x16@')
# returns:
'020c6a40595b050c4e403e4741595242560f443d47501640'
```

This uses a format-string (f-string) to convert each byte `b` to a hex value (`f'{:x}'`), but also pads the string to length 2 with a leading 0 (`f'{:0>2}'`).

Comment: That seems to do the same thing as binascii.hexlify(). But I guess that is what I am after then, even though design wise I need something else. My design is flawed.